In Power Query, how do I calculate difference between numerical values of two rows in a table?
A Power Query / BI newbie here. I have the following sample data table:



DateTime
Process
Activity
ElapsedProcessTime(s)
TimeInterval(s) (expected output)




17/Jul/2024 00:00:00
A
1
0
0


17/Jul/2024 00:10:00
A
2
600
600


17/Jul/2024 00:15:01
A
3
901
301


17/Jul/2024 00:15:45
A
4
945
44


17/Jul/2024 01:00:00
B
1
0
0


17/Jul/2024 01:10:00
B
2
600
600


17/Jul/2024 01:15:01
B
3
901
301


17/Jul/2024 01:15:45
B
4
945
44


17/Jul/2024 14:00:00
C
1
0
0


17/Jul/2024 14:05:00
C
2
300
300


17/Jul/2024 14:15:01
C
3
901
601


17/Jul/2024 14:15:55
C
4
955
54



I need a Power Query formula that calculates the TimeInterval(s) column using the data from the other columns as shown above. The Time Interval value needs to be difference between the current and previous Elapsed Time value, resetting to zero whenever Process has changed.
I can do this in Excel easily by referencing the previous cell and calculating the difference using a simple formula and conditional statements, but I just can't figure out how to do this in Power Query.

Try this below.
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "GroupOnMe", each try if #"Added Index"{[Index2]-1}[Process] = [Process] then null else [Index2] otherwise [Index2]),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"GroupOnMe"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"GroupOnMe"}, {{"data", each
    let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
    in Table.AddColumn(a, "TimeInterval(s)", each try [#"ElapsedProcessTime(s)"]-a{[Index]-1}[#"ElapsedProcessTime(s)"] otherwise [#"ElapsedProcessTime(s)"])
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn( Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"GroupOnMe"}), "data", {"DateTime", "Process","Activity", "ElapsedProcessTime(s)", "TimeInterval(s)"}, {"DateTime", "Process","Activity", "ElapsedProcessTime(s)", "TimeInterval(s)"})
in #"Expanded data"


Math corrected, thank you for pointing it out!

Finally had a chance to try this out. In the "Expanded data" line, why is the list of columns in { } repeated in the function Table.ExpandTableColumn?

first is name of the columns you want to expand out of the grouping, second is the name you want to assign to those expanded columns

My actual data table has 1k+ rows, which extracts data from 100+ csv files into one table. It seems when I try to run the line to calculate TimeInterval(s), the query seems to enter an endless loop of downloading the same data from all the csv files again and again, and never finishes adding the new column. I allowed it to run for 1hr+ to no avail.

Sorry you have not  provided enough info to help you.  I have no idea how you modified my code to combine and/or act on combined files, and that wasn't part of your question.

I agree, 1k+ rows itself shouldn't take 2h (from my own experience, even with badly written code, it takes 10minutes at most). So I guess your code is extracting data from 100 csv files, instead of extracting data from one table that consolidates 100 csv files.

I think you can replicate your Excel formula in power query by sorting your data by Process and DateTime first, and then add a "custom column" in power query that mirrors your Excel formula.
To reference "previous" row, you just need to add an index column (like in previous answer).

The M code:
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  sorted = Table.Sort(Source, {{"Process", Order.Ascending}, {"DateTime", Order.Ascending}}),
  addIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(sorted, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  calcTimeInterval = Table.AddColumn(addIndex, "TimeInterval(s)", each if [Index] = 0 or[Process] <> sorted[Process]{[Index] - 1} then 0 else [#"ElapsedProcessTime(s)"] - sorted[#"ElapsedProcessTime(s)"]{[Index] - 1}),
  removeUnused = Table.RemoveColumns(calcTimeInterval, {"Index"})
in
  removeUnused


Thank you for the suggestion. My actual data table has 1k+ rows, which extracts data from 100+ csv files into one table. It seems when I try to run the line to calculate TimeInterval(s), the query seems to enter an endless loop of downloading the same data from all the csv files again and again and never finishes adding the new column. I allowed it to run for 1hr+ to no avail.

In my code, sorted[#"ElapsedProcessTime(s)"]{[Index] - 1} references previous "ElapsedProcessTime(s)". where "sorted" is a table name. how did you adapt it in your own code? @MrTea
